Inspection lot : Update UD just for point in code
I want to simulate a change of UD (only for UD = A) in the Inspection lot only for an inspection point - as can be done in QA32
I did not find a suitable BAPI that I could use.
Would you happen to know how to implement this?
I found BAPIs that can be used for changing the UD of the test - but I want only for a specific test point
